# extracting text using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string variable which contains

```
"A regular expression is an object that describes a pattern of characters.

<strong>Regular expressions are used to perform pattern-matching.</strong> and "search-and-replace" functions on text.
```

I have to extract

```
 "<strong>Regular expressions are used to perform pattern-matching</strong>"
```

For this i am using

```
^<strong>([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)</strong>$
```

regular expression.
But it is not working.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<strong>([^<]*)</strong>
```

or this

```
<strong>([A-Za-z0-9-\s.]+)</strong>
```

Your expression does not work because of the following:

1. ^ and $ mean beginning and end of string. So pattern will match only when nothing is before `<strong>` and nothing is after `</strong>`. In your case you have text after `</strong>`
2. You missed period in your character class expression. It would be **([A-Za-z0-9-\s.]+)**

Answer (score 0):

The dot before the closing tag is not being matched if you are trying to match `<strong>Regular expressions are used to perform pattern-matching.</strong>`